# Deleted everything on my system and now nothing works

Tags: command-line, apt

By mistake I deleted everything from Ubuntu and now even I can't open any folders. The `apt-get` command is also not working...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us _exactly_ what you did. How did you "delete everything"? What command did you run? Have you rebooted since deleting (if you haven't, don't!)?

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything how this happened

Comment: If you have any idea how can I run apt-get command, please let me know...it is showing command not found

Comment: Is it found if you give the full path `/usr/bin/apt-get`?

Comment: If you deleted everything, you deleted also the command apt-get and its configuration ... How you pretend to execute it? If you reboot the PC what does it happen?\

Comment: Is there a backup of your important files?

Comment: We can't help if you don't tell us what you did. How did you delete everything? Did you run a command? What makes you say you deleted everything? What symptoms are you seeing? If you tried something (like running `apt-get`), you need to tell us! Add it to your question and also show the exact errors you are getting.

Answer (score 3):

If you deleted everything (`rm -rf /` or equivalent), then:

- If you have no important data on the disk, just reinstall.
- If you have important data than you want to (attempt to) recover:

  - cut off power immediately (the less is written to the disk, the better)
  - boot from an external disk and run a file recovery program (ideally, boot from an external disk, make a bit-copy of your disk with `dd`, and work on that)